# Is there a term when a 2-ary function takes the same argument twice?

Tags: functions, terminology

Lots of functions of two arguments have interesting behavior when the two arguments have the same value. Easy examples off the top of my head, with *Mathematica*-esque prefix syntax:

$\texttt{Plus}[x,x]=x + x = 2x$

$\texttt{Subtract}[x,x] = x - x = 0$

$\texttt{Times}[x,x] = x \times x = x^2$

$\texttt{Divide}[x,x] = x / x = 1$

$\texttt{And}[a,a] = a \wedge a = \texttt{Or}[a,a] = a \vee a = a$

$\texttt{ShortestPath}[v,v] = \delta(v,v) = 0$

$\texttt{Binomial}[n,n] = \begin{pmatrix}n \\ n\end{pmatrix} = 1$

$\texttt{Dot}[v,v] = \vec{v} \cdot \vec{v} = ||\vec{v}||^2$

$\texttt{Log}[x,x] = \log_x{x} = 1$

$\texttt{Integrate}[f,x,x] = \int_x^x{f(t)\,dt}=0$

$\texttt{Union}[S,S] = S \cup S = S$

Of course, not all functions have a special case here. For example, I am not aware of $x^x$, $\sqrt[x]{x}$, or $\texttt{Round}[x,x]$ having any interesting and general ($x \ne 0$) behavior.

Is there a general term for special cases in 2-ary functions where the same argument is supplied twice, $f(x,x)$?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to name -- the property of taking the same arguments, or the product of such a process? By the way, what's $\text{Round}$?

Comment: You could study the behaviour of functions from $X \times X$ to $Y$ with the restriction that the two arguments had to be the same but this would seem to be just a strange way to study functions from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: I guess I am looking for the name of the case. Lots of functions have special behavior when 0 ("zero case") or 1 ("case of x=1") is supplied as an argument. Likewise, in programming you often have to worry about the "null case" and "empty case" for your input.

By `Round` I meant rounding to a specific number decimal places, such as `Round[3.14159,2] == 3.14`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the set $\{ (x, x) \mid x \in X\}$ is usually called the *diagonal* of $X \times X$. Thus if $f:X \times X \to Y$ is a function, you could perhaps call the function $x \mapsto f(x,x)$ the *diagonal* of $f$.